# Convert certain vb.net code to c#

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am converting a class library from vb.net to C#. Everything is fine, but in one function that I am converting I am having trouble with it.

**VB.NET Code**

```
Protected Function CloseButtonOfTabPage(ByVal tp As TabPage) As PictureBox
    Return (From item In CloseButtonCollection Where item.Value Is tp Select item.Key).FirstOrDefault
End Function
```

Where CloseButtonOfTabPage is a System.Collection.Generic.Dictionary

I am having trouble converting this code. Can any body help me?

Comment: The actual code line code can be converted by making the keywords lowercase.

Comment: try this tool... it works almost always...  http://converter.telerik.com/

Answer (score 0):

Assumed your dictionary has the correct types for key and value, this code in C# should do it:

```
protected PictureBox CloseButtonOfTabPage(TabPage tp)
{
   return CloseButtonCollection
          .Where(item => item.Value == tp)
          .Select(item => item.Key).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

(and you surely meant `CloseButtonCollection` is a dictionary, not `CloseButtonOfTabPage`).

Answer (score 0):

Also a possible code sample: (using LINQ)

```
protected PictureBox CloseButtonOfTabPage(TabPage tp)
{
    return (from item in CloseButtonCollection
            where item.Value == tp
            select item.Key).FirstOrDefault();
}
```